# How to make a sql server query that converts one row with From Date To Date columns to multiple rows for each day or each month

Tags: sql-server

How to make a sql server query that converts one row with From Date To Date columns to multiple rows for each day or each month?
I have the row shown in the attached image, what I want is to view each loan installment in a separate row according to its month[Table Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHbmL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a calendar table

```
;WITH calendar
     AS (SELECT dates = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-04-22') -- pass the minimum date range
         UNION ALL
         SELECT dates = Dateadd(Day, 1, dates)
         FROM   calendar
         WHERE  dates < '2017-02-27') -- pass the maximum date range
SELECT *
FROM   calendar c
       JOIN yourtable y
         ON c.dates BETWEEN cast(y.StartDate as date) AND cast(y.EndDate as date)
```

Since you care about minimum of day level I have removed time part from `StartDate` and `EndDate` in Join condition.

If you want the result in monthly level the replace `Day` with `Month` in `DATEADD` function `Dateadd(Month, 1, dates)`

I have used `Recursive CTE` to generate dates, but it is always good to have calendar table created in our database.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by recursive cte, but without additional joinig as well:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Test varchar(5), DateFrom date, DateTo date);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('a', '2016-01-15', '2016-01-31'), ('b', '2016-12-01', '2016-12-11');

WITH cte AS(
  SELECT Test, DateFrom, DateTo
    FROM @t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Test, Dateadd(d, 1, DateFrom), DateTo
    FROM cte
    WHERE Dateadd(d, 1, DateFrom) <= DateTo
)
SELECT Test, DateFrom AS YourDate
  FROM cte
  ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: didnt think about it +1... but I still prefer Calendar table

Comment: Yes, a "real" calender table might come in handy in numerous sitiuations... ideally extended by weekday, week number, etc.